In Blazor, C# and Postgresql I can't make an INSERT INTO using Blazor EditForm
In Blazor EditForm I use C# and Postgresql to INSERT data from a EditForm (Blazor)
into the database table.
But for some reason it doesn't approve the data. Instead there Is an error message for the C# script saying that
So basically what I want to accomplish is to INSERT data into Postgres Database Table by using the EditForm.
I use a Model attribute added to the EditForm alongside InputText with a @bind-Value as you can see in the code.
Here is the Razor File
@page "/register"
@using Login.Models;
@using Npgsql;
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<PageTitle>Register</PageTitle>

<EditForm method="post" Model="Register2" OnValidSubmit="RegisterForm" FormName="Register" Enhance>
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <InputText id="username" @bind-Value="Register2.username"/>
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <InputText id="email" @bind-Value="Register2.email"/>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <InputText type="password" id="password" @bind-Value="Register2.password"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
</EditForm>

@code
{
    [SupplyParameterFromForm] private Register2 Register2 { get; set; } = new();
    
    private string connectionString;

    public string? username { get; } = "";
    public string? password { get; } = "";
    public string? email { get; } = "";
    
    private string localhost = "localhost";

    private string user = "hidden";

    private string pass = "hidden"

    private string db = "hidden";

    private string tbl = "hidden";

    public async Task RegisterForm()
    {
        connectionString = $"host={localhost};username={user};password={pass};database={db}";
        using var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        var register = $@"insert into {tbl}(username, email, password) values(@username, @email, @password)";
        var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(register, connection);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/User");
    }
}

Here is the C# script
namespace Login.Models;
using Npgsql;

public class Register2
{
    private string connectionString;

    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; } = "";
    
    private string localhost = "localhost";

    private string user = "postgres";

    private string pass = "NewPass123";

    private string db = "individual_assignment_db";

    private string tbl = "users";
    
    //Summarized you basically validate input with two form fields...
    public Register2()
    {
        connectionString = $"host={localhost};username={user};password={pass};database={db}";
        using var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        var register = $@"insert into {tbl}(username, email, password) values(@username, @email, @password)";
        var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(register, connection);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", "Nick");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", "nickgatsfield@gmail.com");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", "abcdefgh");
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }    
}


"there Is an error message for the C# script saying that" what?? what is the error message, stack trace and which line?

I find it totally bizarre that you use Microsoft's most modern UI framework, coupled with the most prehistoric way of accessing a database posssible. How are such things even in the same tutorial?

Your tbl var is an injection risk

@Charlieface the error message is "InvalidOperationException: Parameter '@username' must have either its NpgsqlDbType or its DataTypeName or its Value set." Stacktrace is cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Is username null?

Yeah username is whatever value is inserted into the EditForm InputText, using @bind-Value

Why don't you use EF Core as ORM?

According to this GitHub issue, the underlying root cause could be that the types of parameters are not inferred.
One: Specify type:
You should specify the type of parameters explicitly. There are multiple approaches for that:
One way would be:
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@username", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar) { Value = "Nick" });

Two: Use DbNull, not null!
As mentioned here,

To represent a null parameter value, set Value to DBNull.Instance, not null.
you should use DbNull for assigning null values:

There is a utility extension method here which does both things for you:
private static NpgsqlParameter safeNpgsqlParameter<T>( string parameterName, T? data ) where T : struct =>
    data switch {
        decimal => new NpgsqlParameter() { ParameterName = parameterName, NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlDbType.Numeric, Value = data },
        Enum    => new NpgsqlParameter() { ParameterName = parameterName, Value = data },
        null    => new NpgsqlParameter() { ParameterName = parameterName, Value = DBNull.Value },
        LocalDate => new NpgsqlParameter() {
            ParameterName = parameterName,
            NpgsqlDbType  = NpgsqlDbType.Date,
            Value         = data
        },
        _ => throw new DbUpdateException()
    };

